# Javascript functions not calculating the fields

Tags: javascript, forms, function

My javascript functions are not pulling the values from the input fields and performing the calculations. I am trying to create a form that:

1) allows input for start time, end time, and rate of pay, 
2) calculates the total hours (start-end), 
3) multiplies total hours by rate of pay to get the total pay for time period, 
4) onclick returns the total pay as innerhtml.

I can't figure out why the function won't fetch the values from the html and perform the calculations. Any thoughts? I am a newbie at this. I tried adding the function to the onclick, I tried calling the function in the button, put the variables inside the function, pointing the button to the variable that holds the total, and 100 other things, and I'm still stuck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title> Babysitter Pay Calculator </title>
    <script>


        function calculate (enterAfternoonEndTime, enterAfternoonStartTime, enterAfternoonPayRate) {

            return totalAfternoonPay;


        var afternoonStartTime = document.getElementbyId("enterAfternoonStartTime").value;//military time
        var afternoonEndTime = document.getElementbyId("enterAfternoonEndTime").value;
        var afternoonPayRate = document.getElementbyId("enterAfternoonPayRate").value; 
        var totalAfternoonPay = (enterAfternoonEndTime - enterAfternoonStartTime) * enterAfternoonPayRate
            }
        </script>
</head>

<body>

        <h1>Welcome to the Babysitter Calculator!</h1>
        <p> Pay is calculated for the following shifts: </p>
            <ul>
                <li>Afternoon: 5:00pm - 8:00pm </li>
                <li>Evening: 8:01pm - Midnight</li>
                <li>Overnight: 12:01am - 4:00am</li>
            </ul>   


        <p> 
            <label>Enter afternoon start time (i.e, 13:00 = 1pm):</label>
            <input type = "number" name="enterAfteroonStartTime" id="enterAfteroonStartTime" /> 
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Enter afternoon end time:</label>
            <input type = "number" name ="enterAfternoonEndTime" id = "enterAfternoonEndTime" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Enter afternoon pay rate:</label>
            <input type = "number" name="enterAfternoonPayRate" id = "enterAfternoonPayRate"/> 
        </p>

        <button type="button" onclick="function calculate"> Calculate! </button>

        <p id = showcalculation>
            <label> Total Pay Per Shift: </label> 
            <script> document.getElementbyId(var totalAfternoonPay).innerhtml = "totalAfternoonPay";</script>
        </p>    



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have several syntax errors in your code. you can use the browser's developer console to see those errors. please fix them and update your question. Also heads up: it's `document.getElementById` you also have a typo there, and  it should be`onclick=calculate()`

Answer (score 0):

You have a large number of errors in your code. Undeclared variables, incorrect use of the `onClick`, unexpected tokens. I made as few changes as possible to what you did to make it work, but there are some fundamentals you should work on here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Babysitter Pay Calculator </title>
  <script>
    function calculate() {
        var afternoonStartTime = document.getElementById("enterAfteroonStartTime").value; //military time
        var afternoonEndTime = document.getElementById("enterAfternoonEndTime").value;
        var afternoonPayRate = document.getElementById("enterAfternoonPayRate").value;
        var totalAfternoonPay = (afternoonEndTime - afternoonStartTime) * afternoonPayRate / 100;
        document.getElementById('pay').innerText = totalAfternoonPay;
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Welcome to the Babysitter Calculator!</h1>
   <p> Pay is calculated for the following shifts: </p>
   <ul>
      <li>Afternoon: 5:00pm - 8:00pm </li>
      <li>Evening: 8:01pm - Midnight</li>
      <li>Overnight: 12:01am - 4:00am</li>
   </ul>

   <p>
      <label>Enter afternoon start time (i.e, 13:00 = 1pm):</label>
      <input type="number" name="enterAfteroonStartTime" id="enterAfteroonStartTime" />
   </p>

   <p>
      <label>Enter afternoon end time:</label>
      <input type="number" name="enterAfternoonEndTime" id="enterAfternoonEndTime" />
   </p>

   <p>
      <label>Enter afternoon pay rate:</label>
      <input type="number" name="enterAfternoonPayRate" id="enterAfternoonPayRate" />
   </p>

   <button type="button" onclick="calculate()"> Calculate! </button>

   <p id=s howcalculation>
      <label> Total Pay Per Shift: </label>
      <span id="pay"></span>
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a bunch of errors. I'll list some of them so you can see basically what's wrong:

1. `<p id = showcalculation>` should be `<p id="showcalculation">`
2. `<button type="button" onclick="function calculate">` is wrong at the "onclick" attribute. You need to invoke the function, not redeclare it. It should be `<button type="button" onclick="calculate();">`
3. Your function is returning a value before making the calculation. `return` statement should be at end, when you're indeed returning something.
4. You are obtaining all the data that are required for calculation using `document.getElementById` to get the values. Using this, you don't need parameters anymore
5. `document.getElementbyId(var totalAfternoonPay).innerhtml = "totalAfternoonPay";` is completely wrong. You need to pass the selector to `getElementById` function instead of declaring another variables on it. Check my snippet to see the correct way
6. Pay attention to casing. All functions are case-sensitive. `document.getElementbyId` won't work. The correct is `document.getElementById`.

Try to read some tutorials or read some books about programming. Going into it without having the basics won't make you understand the way to go. Also use some IDE's like VSCode or Visual Studio. It'll give you some advices about wrong written code and will save your time :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title> Babysitter Pay Calculator </title>
   <script>
      function calculate () {
      
      var afternoonStartTime = document.getElementById("enterAfternoonStartTime").value;//military time
       var afternoonEndTime = document.getElementById("enterAfternoonEndTime").value;
       var afternoonPayRate = document.getElementById("enterAfternoonPayRate").value; 
       var totalAfternoonPay = (afternoonEndTime - afternoonStartTime) * afternoonPayRate
      
      document.getElementById("totalAfternoonPay").innerHTML = totalAfternoonPay;
      
          }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Welcome to the Babysitter Calculator!</h1>
   <p> Pay is calculated for the following shifts: </p>
   <ul>
      <li>Afternoon: 5:00pm - 8:00pm </li>
      <li>Evening: 8:01pm - Midnight</li>
      <li>Overnight: 12:01am - 4:00am</li>
   </ul>
   <p> 
      <label>Enter afternoon start time (i.e, 13:00 = 1pm):</label>
      <input type = "number" name="enterAfternoonStartTime" id="enterAfternoonStartTime" /> 
   </p>
   <p>
      <label>Enter afternoon end time:</label>
      <input type = "number" name ="enterAfternoonEndTime" id = "enterAfternoonEndTime" />
   </p>
   <p>
      <label>Enter afternoon pay rate:</label>
      <input type = "number" name="enterAfternoonPayRate" id = "enterAfternoonPayRate"/> 
   </p>
   <p >
   </p>
   <button type="button" onclick="calculate();"> Calculate! </button>
   <p id = "showcalculation">
      <label> Total Pay Per Shift:<span id="totalAfternoonPay"></span> </label> 
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```